# NGINX + Certbot + Flask - CORS issue

Tags: python, nginx, ssl, flask, lets-encrypt

I have searched a lot, for more than 4 hours, reading dozens of forums and guides and couldn't understand why I am getting CORS issues when trying to call my API.

Here is the `app.py` file:

```
from flask_jwt_extended import JWTManager
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from config import conn_string

app = Flask(__name__)
# CORS(app, resources={r"/api/*": {"origins": "http://localhost:5000"}}) # I think I tried all the available options here!
CORS(app)

app.config["JWT_SECRET_KEY"] = "fe7e8955db51c0ff78550419434128cb"
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = conn_string
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = True
app.config['JSON_SORT_KEYS'] = False

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
jwt = JWTManager(app)
```

And my `controller.py` that contains the routes:

```
from flask_jwt_extended import jwt_required, create_access_token, get_jwt_identity
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
from app import app, db

import wsgiserver

@app.route("/api/authenticate", methods=["POST"])
def login():
    username = request.json["username"]
    password_hash = hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac('sha256', request.json["password"].encode('utf-8'), b'bytemine', 100000).hex()
    password_hash_verify = "blablabla"

    if password_hash == password_hash_verify:
        access_token = create_access_token(identity=username, expires_delta=timedelta(days=1))
        return jsonify(message="Authenticated", access_token=access_token), 200
    else:
        return jsonify(message="Incorrect Credentials"), 403


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if os.environ['FLASK_ENV'] == "development":
        app.run()
    else:
        print("Starting WSGI...")
        # server = wsgiserver.WSGIServer(app, port=5000, certfile='/etc/letsencrypt/live/vsbapi.bytemine.io/fullchain.pem', keyfile='/etc/letsencrypt/live/vsbapi.bytemine.io/privkey.pem')
        server = wsgiserver.WSGIServer(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)
        server.start()
```

I am using **NGINX** and **Certbot**:

```
cat www.vsbapi.bytemine.io.conf
```

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:5000/api;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
}
server {
    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:5000/api;
    }
    server_name vsbapi.bytemine.io www.vsbapi.bytemine.io;
 # managed by Certbot

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/vsbapi.bytemine.io/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/vsbapi.bytemine.io/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}server {
    if ($host = www.vsbapi.bytemine.io) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = vsbapi.bytemine.io) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80 ;
    listen [::]:80 ;
    server_name vsbapi.bytemine.io www.vsbapi.bytemine.io;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

If I try
`controller.py`

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    if os.environ['FLASK_ENV'] == "development":
        app.run()
    else:
        print("Starting WSGI...")
        server = wsgiserver.WSGIServer(app, port=5000, host="0.0.0.0", certfile='/etc/letsencrypt/live/vsbapi.bytemine.io/fullchain.pem', keyfile='/etc/letsencrypt/live/vsbapi.bytemine.io/privkey.pem')
        # server = wsgiserver.WSGIServer(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)
        server.start()
```

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/Bytemine/controller.py", line 153, in <module>
    server = wsgiserver.WSGIServer(app, port=5000, host="0.0.0.0", certfile='/etc/letsencrypt/live/vsbapi.bytemine.io/fullchain.pem', keyfile='/etc/letsencrypt/live/vsbapi.bytemine.io/privkey.pem')
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wsgiserver.py", line 2310, in __init__
    self.ssl_adapter = SSLAdapter(certfile, keyfile, ca_certs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wsgiserver.py", line 1779, in __init__
    cafile=certificate_chain
NameError: name 'certificate_chain' is not defined
```

I am trying to call the API using XHR

```
curl 'https://vsbapi.bytemine.io/api/authenticate/' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="91", "Chromium";v="91"' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer null' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *' \
  -H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' \
  -H 'Referer: https://condescending-spence-081ef7.netlify.app/' \
  -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.77 Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'requestsource: localhost' \
  --data-raw '{"username":"bytemine","password":"xxxxxxxxxxx"}' \
  --compressed
```

Comment: The problem is definitely on nginx side, have you tried to append CORS headers when request come to nginx? https://serverfault.com/a/844963

Comment: Hi @Alveona, I tried this https://gist.github.com/marcelogrsp/b3ac2493e4d35571e64693ade005dd63

Comment: Any luck on this?